# Python and Queue File Management

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, save, queue

My goal is to collect every link of a particular website. This website is a top retail/e-commerce website, so I expect the amount of links that I have to collect to be very high. The idea is to start out by visiting the site map of the page, and collect each link available on that page. Then, for each link that I collected, follow that link and collect another group of links until I can get as many as I can.

The issue that I'm having is with managing a queue. I have been using different ways to keep track of my progress, but I'm having lots of confusion with so many different factors like the structure and different save formats, it seems like there really ought to be some sort of conventions for this?

I found a few different libraries like 'persist-queue' and python's standard queue library, but the main issues are these. I can't figure out to save my queue in between runs, (since the number of links to collect is so large), and the next time the program starts, I need to be able to start from where I left off while also dynamically adding more links to this queue that have not already been evaluated.

There are lots of different components that are  spread out all over my program, so below is just an excerpt of the types of ways that I'm trying to go about this. Basically I'm doing a several series' of checks to properly handle this data, like so:

```
        for souplink in collectedlinks:
            if souplink == '': continue
            if rawsouplink in list_completerawlink: continue
            if souplink in read_listlinks: continue
            if not souplink in list_accumulated:
                file_todo.write(souplink+'\n')
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider simply using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) which does most of this for you.

Check out the documentation for [Link Extractors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) and [Broad Crawls](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html).